# Jenkins keeps resetting the workspace's .git/config

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

On a Jenkins job I have setup two repositories: a local and a remote. The plan is to check the remote periodically, and when it detects change, to push to the local and from there on a custom distributed testing system takes control of the testing and returns the results to Jenkins.

It all works good with one problem. Every time I restart Jenkins, it removes the remote (or local, depends on the weather) repo from the job's workspace's `.git/config` file and I have to edit it manually.

How I have configured the job:

- repo url: `/path/to/local`
- name: `localrepo`
- repo url: `gitolite@someserver:therepo`
- name: `origin`

and the generated `.git/config` only contains:

```
[remote "localrepo"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/localrepo/*
    url = /path/to/local
```

**Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?**

Comment: I can't get this to occur any more. Close it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the Jenkins git plugin. I think you need to let the git plugin control the local git repo and not do any manual configuration behind Jenkins' back.

When you configure a Jenkins job with a remote git repository, you can make Jenkins poll for changes or you can arrange a notification to be delivered to Jenkins e.g. from a git hook script.

When Jenkins detects a change in any of the branches you have told it to build, it will update the git repo in the Jenkins workspace and then it is ready to execute the build steps of the job configuration.

The git repo in the workspace is managed by Jenkins git plugin in a somewhat nonstandard way. You did not exactly specify how the files in git are sent to the custom distributed testing system, so I cannot speculate if the Jenkins workspace is usable for you as-is or if something further needs to be done.

To actually answer your question "what am I doing wrong": You should stop manually changing the configuration of the local git repo in the Jenkins workspace and let the git plugin manage it. If this is not a good solution for you, you may need to stop using the git plugin.

As you seem to be willing to do a lot of repo management by hand, I assume the only thing you need the git plugin for is to poll the remote repo, i.e. to detect changes.

You could use e.g. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/script-scm, which allows you to write a custom script to manage polling and checkout.

Another alternative would be to forget about polling and simply trigger a new build of your job from the post-commit-hook script of the remote git repo. This would allow you to specify "None" for SCM in job configuration and take complete control of the local repo management.

I myself would probably check if it is possible to co-operate with the Jenkins git plugin and use the local git repo as-is. The git plugin gives you some nice things like a list of changes in each build, which you will not have if the job has no SCM.

Comment: This is what I've done: (1) install Jenkins & plugins. (2) set up a new job. (3) set up the new job's git settings. (4) initiate a new build. I did NOT meddle with the workspace until I found out that of the two remotes I had set up (through jenkins' configuration) only one exists (the one that gets polled for changes). The other remote is used by the script that actually distributes and runs the specs.